# How to trim string from one specific character to another in VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

Already used the `trim()` function, it needs to define the position but in my case
I want to fetch the value of character from first underscore(`_`) to second underscore(`_`) .

fileName = **EBGI_13641689_1653559001438_EBAOGIPA_PDOC_PL_GPT**

Output should be like this

```
13641689
```

Comment: Maybe `var first = fileName.IndexOf('_'); return fileName.Substring(first + 1, fileName.IndexOf('_', first) - fileName.IndexOf('_') - 1);` what have you tried so far?

Comment: `fileName = s.Split("_"c).Skip(1).First()` ?

Comment: Or `fileName = s.Split("_"c)(1)` ?

Comment: What you ask isn't trimming.  You're trying to find the second part in that string